# text field like ms Word in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written software that works like Word. I'm stuck in a problem.
If I click to write in my fake software, a text field will return. When I do not write anything in this text field, I want to delete this text field by clicking on another part of the page. And create a new text field.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def do(event):  
  textBox=Text(root, cursor="arrow", fg=None, bd=0, height=1, 
  width=event.x)
  textBox.delete
  textBox.place(x=event.x, y=event.y)

root.config(bg = "red")
root.bind("<Button-1>",do) 
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Text


def destroy_empty_widget(event=None):
    if not event.widget.get('0.0', 'end-1c'):
        event.widget.destroy()


def do(event):
    text_box = Text(
        root, cursor="arrow", fg=None, bd=0,
        height=1, width=10)
    text_box.focus_set()
    text_box.bind('<FocusOut>', destroy_empty_widget)
    text_box.place(x=event.x, y=event.y)


root = Tk()
root.config(bg="red")

root.bind("<Button-1>", do)

root.mainloop()
```

Set keyboard focus to the widget and bind that focusing out will destroy it.

Also:
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

I strongly suggest following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Function and variable names should be in `snake_case`, class names in `CapitalCase`. Don't have space around `=` if it is used as a part of keyword argument (`func(arg='value')`) but have space around `=` if it is used for assigning a value (`variable = 'some value'`). Have space around operators (`+-/` etc.: `value = x + y`(except here `value += x + y`)). Have two blank lines around function and class declarations. Class methods have one blank line around them.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now how do we bet that if the field has a text, it will not be deleted?

Comment: @AmanullahAmini edited code to add that functionality

Comment: Or what other way is there for this purpose ???
I need friends very much, please help me.

Comment: tanks alooooooooooooooot

Comment: Sorry to ask you a question again.
Now how do we edit the inputed fields inside the text?
For example, activate the cursor mode by clicking.

Comment: @AmanullahAmini basically you don't want to bind the even to just `<Button-1>` (the easiest way and really how it should be (a different tool for selection and drawing)) do sth like `root.bind('<Control-Button-1>', do)`, then to create the box you need to press cntrl+mouse button to create the box, and simply click in it to edit

Comment: Thank you dear Master!
Is there any other way I can activate the input field anywhere like MS-Word software or write it like a whiteboard?

Comment: @AmanullahAmini you will need to be more specific on that one, I don't think I quite understand what you want, just be able to draw stuff? or what? if possible provide some images of what you expect and quite possibly **you may need to ask another question about it** (don't forget to provide a [mre] and explain in detail what you want)

Comment: Hello dear professor!
I am a Civil engineering professor. It has been 9 months since we started python programming.
I want to create software that is like a whiteboard to teach by writing and drawing shapes on it.
I want to make software that can write and draw shapes in any part of the screen.

Comment: Because there is a feature in the input field of the tkinter text, it must be written from the first left or from the right.
I want to click on any part of the page to activate the text mode, not just on the right or left

Comment: Is this claim possible in Python?
Or go to another language?

Comment: @AmanullahAmini I think you may want to use the `tkinter.Canvas` widget for something like that, yes, it is technically possible to create this in Python (and probably quite easy especially if you already know the language), tho I would suggest that you ask another question and include in it a [mre] also probably there are questions on here that perhaps already answer this question

Comment: thank you
I mean, you really answered my questions from night until now, which I have been looking for for a month now.
 Thank you again 1000 times.